# Point add-on domain to a subfolder and redirect direct access to that subfolder to add-on domain using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a site `example.com/main` and another `site example2.com.`

I have set up an add-on domain for `example2.com` which shows files in the `main` subfolder in the `example.com` domain. What I want is that when users go to `example2.com`, they REMAIN on `example2.com` while they see files from `example.com/main`. So if they access other files like `main/contact.php`, it shows as `example2.com/contact.php`.

I have successfully done what I mentioned above in the add-on page of cPanel.

My issue:

I want it so that when users visit `example.com/main` directly, I want them to be redirected to `example2.com` and then see the `main` subfolder. I have had no luck as I keep getting stuck in a loop.

Doing `Redirect 301 / http://example2.com/` doesn't work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+main[\s/?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^main(/.*)?$ http://example2.com$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```